# UISplitview can't show full with UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I added

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

in Info.plist

When I run the app, app can't show full.
[image]

Why and how to make full to rightbar in UISplitview ?

Comment: Is this on a device (iPad) or in the simulator?  We see startup problems like this on the Simulator that do not happen on the device.

Comment: We also have seen this problem when creating a window/view in landscape in Interface Guilder, we have found it best to create all interfaces on portrait, even if they will be used on landscape.

Comment: on device ... Can you explain detail ? So, I can't start with UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight . I created all interfaces on portrait .... but can't start with landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the Detail View isn't setup as a Master view? 
Thats what it looks like from your screenshot.

and you might want to change (which could also be an issue):

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad</key>
```

to:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation-ipad</key>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and it is because I had subclassed `UISplitViewController` and accidentally overridden the **private method** `detailViewController`.